# Custom Alertdialog width is bigger than the shown width in layout xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I am trying to create custom alertdialog. Here is my alertdialog custom layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Processing" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the code from activity where i call custom alertdialog

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
   View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutalertprogress, null);
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
   alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
   alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    if(!alertDialog.isShowing())
      {
           alertDialog.show();
      }
```

problem is even in layout file linearlayout width is wrapped to its content like this
[image: layout demo]

the real width of alertdialog looks like this in runtime 
[image]
so the real width of alertdialog is wider (wider than the layout shown above).
It seems that linearlayout width is not wrapped to its contents so there is big unused space from its edges to its child elements. how to make this linearlayout width to wrap its contents so the unused space from its edges can be removed? Thanks

Comment: change parent relative layout width to `wrap_content` from `match_parent`.

Comment: use fixed size to child element of linearlayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

set  background color to child **LinearLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Processing" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then add this line in your java code

```
 alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

after this

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use simply just **setLayout** method with your desired width and height. This will make your dialog width and height as specified.
**Kotlin** version,

```
private fun showDialog() {
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val layout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout, null, false)
    dialog.setView(layout)

    val alert = dialog.create()

    alert.show()
    alert.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
    alert.window?.setLayout(600, 600)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutalertprogress, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));
                if(!alertDialog.isShowing())
                {
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
```

Comment: Hi Prateek Thank you for quick reply. I tried your your solution and it made layout transparent. But problem is i show this alert on imageview so image under it got various colors. So due to that alert may not visible sometimes (depending on the color under it). So i am going after that alertdialog with white background and black text with spinning bar. Thank again for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

change your relative layout as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Processing" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Create a theme for alertdialog in `style.xml` as below

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="AlertDialog.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Create below method to call your dialog.

```
public void showDemoDialog() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demodg, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        if (!alertDialog.isShowing()) {
            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }

    }
```

This is the result when run on device.
[image]

Comment: hi Karan. Thanks for the suggestion :). I tried this and it still the same.

Comment: @d91: sorry I forgot to edit earlier, I have checked, it works. Try and let me know.

Comment: Hi no worries and i tried again. what happened is both spinning bar and textview moved to left in same white space. I am trying to wrap the content so that unnecessary white area goes away. Anyway thanks so much for trying to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and the solution which worked for me is:

Create a theme with the followings:

```
<style name="yourThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
       ...
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And then in code:

```
 inflatedView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutId, null)
  dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.yourThemeName)
            .setView(inflatedView)
  dialog.show()
```